# r - cannot send mail to outlook via mailR

Tags: r, email, shiny, smtp, sendmailr

I am trying to send mail from R to outlook via mailR package, but I keep getting error whenever I try to run it. Here's my code :

```
library(mailR)

send.mail(
    from = "me@companydomain.com",
    to = c("coworker@companydomain.com"),
    subject = "Test Email",
    body = "testing",
    authenticate = TRUE,
    smtp = list(
      host.name = "smtp.office365.com",
      port = ` 587,
      user.name = "me@companydomain.com",
      passwd = "Password",
      tls = TRUE
    ),
  authenticate = TRUE,
  send = TRUE
)
```

The error is get is

```
    org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.office365.com:587
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1410)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1437)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at RJavaTools.invokeMethod(RJavaTools.java:386)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.office365.com, 587; timeout 60000;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.office365.com
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2053)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:697)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:386)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)
    at jaNULL
vax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1400)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.office365.com
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:310)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:236)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2019)
    ... 13 more
Error: EmailException (Java): Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.office365.com:587
```

Comment: The error references gmail's SMTP server (smtp.gmail.com). That should not be the case if you are sending the mail via a company outlook installation.

Comment: i have changed the error I was getting

Comment: Looks like the issue is not specfic to office365, as you had the same issue with gmail!? Can you send emails through them or any other SMTP from your machine with a mail client like thunderbird?
Also, in your code you seem to have a misplaced tick "port =` 587".

Comment: I have only tried on gmail and outlook so far and it doesn't work. I changed the tick on port and nothing happened

Comment: Could be a network configuration thing. Especially if you are in a company network or behind a VPN. You could try different SMTP servers and also different machines, maybe a machine that is in a different network.

Comment: I tried port = 465 and  ssl = true instead of port = 587 and tls = true but no luck

Comment: What is the exact error as returned by the SMTP server?

Comment: Caused by: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.office365.com, 587; timeout 60000;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.office365.com

Comment: I remember mailR was difficult for me as well. Try `library(emayili)`